# Forcing Tesseract to recognize only digits

Tags: java, android, tesseract

I am developing an OCR application for Android. At some point I have observed that I needed to recognize only digits, so I am trying to get the OCR to recognize only digits and hyphens, and not letters or any other type of character.

I have done this:

```
tessBaseAPI.init(path, "eng");
        tessBaseAPI.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "1234156787901299-");
```

But I am not getting an accurate result. Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDITTED:
This is my complete code:

```
tessApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);
      tessApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "0123456789");
      tessApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz");
```

Comment: I want to eliminate all the characters except digits.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain exactly how the result you're getting isn't accurate. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Maximillian: For example, if I have PIN as a letter on the captured photo it becomes: 11211. The alphabets takes a digit format so it induces error in my reading. I want to skip anything alphabet during the reading instead of the alphabets being transformed to digits. Thanks